# Divide by zero error when using >, < or <> in Where statement. No division operator involved

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two CTEs using the same table which holds receipts. Receipt type "a" says how much is billed and may or may not have an amount received. Receipt type "b"s have how much was received if it was received outside of the original receipt. These are matched up by mnth, cusnbr and job. Also on the receipt is how much is allocated for different expenses on the receipt.

I am trying to total up peoples hours if the receipt has been paid at least 99%. These records are based on cusnbr, jobnbr and mnth also. The code below works fine.

```
with billed as(Select cusnbr 
,job
,mnth
,sum(bill_item_1) as 'Billed Item'
,sum(billed) as 'Billed'
From accounting
Where mytype in ('a','b')
Group by cusnbr
,job
,mnth)

paid as(Select cusnbr 
,job
,mnth
,sum(rcpt_item_1) as 'Rcpt Item'
,sum(billed) as 'Paid'
From accounting
Where mytype in ('a','b')
Group by cusnbr
,job
,mnth)


Select b.cusnbr
,b.job
,b.mnth
,sum(g.hours) as 'Total Hours'
,b.[Billed Item]
,p.[Rcpt Item]
From billed b inner join paid p
on b.cusnbr = p.cusnbr
and b.job = p.job
and b.mnth = p.mnth
inner join guys g
on b.cusnbr = g.cusnbr
and b.job = g.job
and b.mnth = g.mnth
Where p.[Paid]/b.Billed > .99
```

The issue I'm having is if I try to add

```
and b.[Billed Item] <> 0
```

To the where clause.

I get "Divide by zero error encountered"

I have tried making the last query a CTE with

```
case when b.[Billed Item] = 0 then 1 else 0 end as flag
```

and then making another query which checks that flag <> 0
I have tried using isnull(b.[Billed Item],0) in the last query as well as isnull(bill_item_1,0) in the first CTE.

I can get around this issue by dumping the whole thing into a temp table and querying that, but just want to know why this is happening. Using ">","<" or "<>" against b.[Billed Item] results in a divide by zero error.

Comment: What do you mean: *No division operator involved* in your title? What is this: `Where p.[Paid]/b.Billed > .99`?

Comment: Your issue seems to be here - "Where p.[Paid]/b.Billed > .99". b.billed has 0 and you can not make a calculation like N/0.

Comment: @forpas It works fine with just `Where p.[Paid]/b.Billed > .99` so I was thinking that this piece had nothing to do with the error I received when I added  `b.[Billed Item] <> 0` However, The answer below seems to prove otherwise. I'm still struggling to see how the two are related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `nullif()`:

```
Where p.[Paid] / nullif(b.Billed, 0) > 0.99
```

This will return `null` -- which does not meet the condition.  You can also phrase this more simply without division as:

```
where p.paid > b.billed * 0.99
```

Comment: Both of the solutions you proposed worked. However, I'm struggling to understand why. The query works fine when I don't include b.[Billed Item] <> 0. I would think that b.Billed and b.[Billed Item] would not be related except for that they are both the result of aggregates in the first CTE. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Michael . . . The order of operations in a query is determined by the optimizer and the execution plan.  Sometimes, a filtering clause that is intended to stop an error can change the execution plan, pushing the evaluation of the expression earlier -- and causing the error.  I would advise you to go with the second solution (multiplication) so there is simply no possibility of an error.

Comment: If you can replace division with multiplication by re-writing an expression, do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you question specifically, but I can tell you that SQL does not process all commands if it does not need to.  For example,

```
SELECT COUNT(1/0)
```

Happily returns 1.  So it is quite possible the order of the conditions cause the optimizer to filter out an uncessary division by zero condition.